# How to restrict access to 'peer chaincode upgrade' to specific organisation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

Is it possible to restrict the 'peer chaincode upgrade' command to specific organisation? I would like one organisation to act as an 'maintenance officer' for the whole network.

I'm setting up a Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.3 network with three organisations: Org1, Org2, Org3. The network uses single channel and several Private Data collections to share sensitive data between organisations. I would like to add fourth organisation to the running network. I know how to generate necessary crypto material, bring up additional Docker containers, join the channel and install chaincode. However, adding fourth organisation, requires additional Private Data collections which have to be specified in 'peer channel upgrade' command using '--collections-config' parameter.
Currently everything works fine. I use CLI of Peer0 from Org1 to issue all 'peer chaincode ...' commands. However I would like to restrict access to this functionality to some other organisation, for example: only Admin from Org3 can issue 'peer chaincode upgrade'.
I tried changing the Channel/Policies/Admins section of configtx.yaml to:

```
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin')"
```

but I am still able to issue 'peer chaincode upgrade' from Peer0.Org1 CLI.

Application section of my configtx.yaml:

```
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        Org1MemberPolicy:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
        Org2MemberPolicy:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.member')"
        Org3MemberPolicy:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.member')"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Channel section of my configtx.yaml:

```
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities
```

Profiles section of my configtx.yaml:

```
Profiles:
    ThreeOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org3
    Orgs123Channel:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

I assume that this is configurable somewhere in configtx.yaml, but I cannot figure out where exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access control for instantiating or upgrading chaincode is handled via instantiation policies.  Instantiation policies are defined as part of the chaincode package using the `-i` option:

```
peer chaincode package -n mycc -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/example02/cmd -v 0 -s -S -i "AND('OrgA.admin')" ccpack.out
```

In Fabric v2.x and later (coming soon), the new chaincode lifecycle model provides much better control of this as well.

Comment: Thank you Gari for this answer. I saved me a lot of effort. Can you tell me why are the '-s -S' options necessary for this to work? I've read the docs, but description of '-s' option ('create CC deployment spec for owner endorsements instead of raw CC deployment spec') is still not clear for me. What difference do these options make to the output?

Comment: `-s` and `-S` are used too create signed chaincode packages.  I'm pretty sure that when you attach an instantiation policy you need to sign the package (but you can try without it as well)

Comment: I tried it and you are right. If I remove ```-s``` and ```-S```, then the package is created, but instantiation policy is not enforced. I am free to instantiate the chaincode even if the policy is violated.